# Bind datarepeater itemtemplate to dynamically generated datatable

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a  dynamically filled datatable called "table" . Am taking item template in the datarepeater. the item template is taken as link button.
How can i bind the dynamic datatable to the datarepeater?

Comment: please provide some code

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have dynamically created a `DataTable` named `dt`. And you have a `DataRepeater` control named `dataRepeater1`. With that, you can use following code to bind `dt` to your repeater:

```
dataRepeater1.DataSource = dt;
dataRepeater1.DataBind();
```